# how to mahe searsh using roles of FOSUserBundle?

Tags: symfony

In the controller i need to test by roles is_granted but it  isn't working because i need to create a notification for all how have ROLE_ADMIN.i try this but no result: `$admins=$em->getRepository('RegisterUserBundle:User')->findByRoles("ROLE_ADMIN");`
but no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think there’s a default `findByRoles` method in `FOSUserBundle`.

I guess you should add yourself a method in your UserRepository like:

```
<?php
public function findByRole($role) {
    $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('u')
            ->from($this->_entityName, 'u')
            ->where('u.roles LIKE :roles')
            ->setParameter('roles', '%"' . $role . '"%');
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

And then in your controller use the method as:

```
$users = $em->getRepository('YourUserBundle:User')->findByRole('ROLE_ADMIN');
```